# Android log being spammed with "qmi_cci_get_ref: ref_count increased 2"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, logcat

I am developing an app with Android Jetpack Compose and found that the log is bloated with the same two log lines indefinitely in a high frequency (see time stamps):

```
2022-06-13 18:22:46.038 1097-1184/? E/QMI_FW: qmi_cci_get_ref: ref count increased 2
2022-06-13 18:22:46.038 1097-1184/? I/ASH: @ 1673484.579: tcs3701: stop power rail pending_off timer
2022-06-13 18:22:46.125 1097-1184/? E/QMI_FW: qmi_cci_get_ref: ref count increased 2
2022-06-13 18:22:46.125 1097-1184/? I/ASH: @ 1673484.666: tcs3701: stop power rail pending_off timer
2022-06-13 18:22:46.212 1097-1184/? E/QMI_FW: qmi_cci_get_ref: ref count increased 2
2022-06-13 18:22:46.212 1097-1184/? I/ASH: @ 1673484.753: tcs3701: stop power rail pending_off timer
2022-06-13 18:22:46.300 1097-1184/? E/QMI_FW: qmi_cci_get_ref: ref count increased 2
...
```

I wonder whether this indicates a problem that should be fixed. Does anyone know what those two lines mean?
I only found this [Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/4064) mentioning the same log line, but the issue was closed with the non-responsive info "not an issue".

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Doe the PIDs 1097 1184 belong to your app? If not ignore them. Because high frequent LogCat messages are nothing unusual for certain devices. Especially devices "polluted" by a large number of apps and services like Samsung devices can show 2-20 entries per second.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, indeed turns out to be a false alarm, the pid does not match. Wasn't aware of the fact that this number was the process id. 
Still surprises me though, as I have a Google Pixel, which I inuitively would not have considered to be polluted.

Comment: In this case it doesn't seem to be caused by an app. Instead it seems to be a system service from Qualcomm (QMI = Qualcomm MSM Interface)